# How can I remove the #n/a from a complex formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AI57,SALESCODES!$B:$G,3,FALSE),(VLOOKUP(AI57,SALESCODES!$C:$G,2,FALSE)))
```

How do I remove the #N/A on this formula?

Comment: Do you know why you get an #N/A ? Can it access the salescodes workbook? Meaning, does it have permission?

Comment: Yes, if it isn't finding the information then it returns an N/A.

Comment: Use [Evaluate Formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-HP010066254.aspx) to identify which part of your formula is introducing the error.

Comment: You probably just need a second IFERROR for the second lookup...

Comment: Couldn't you wrap the whole equation in IF(ISNA()) ?

Comment: @Wutnaut Yes, in this case you could, but the `iferror` will handle other types of errors as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is `IFERROR(value, value if error)` where `value` *and* `value if error` can **both** result ***in an error***.

The only way to avoid this is to handle the error for each of the vlookups. I can't show you what to do because I don't know what result you desire or why you're handling the errors. I'd guess this would work -

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AI57,SALESCODES!$B:$G,3,FALSE),IFERROR((VLOOKUP(AI57,SALESCODES!$C:$G,2,FALSE)),"Value if error")`

Comment: @greene, remember, if it worked, mark it as the answer